# How this equation converted to the other form?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I want to know how equation number 1 converted to equation number 2 ?

Equation number 1:

[image]

$$R_{TH}=\frac{R_1R_2}{R_1+R_2}$$

Equation number 2:

[image]

$$R_1=\frac{R_{TH}R_2}{R_2-R_{TH}}$$

Comment: Cross multiply and solve for $R_1$.

Comment: I'd guess that the things which were said in the comments [when you originally posted this on meta](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/32741/how-this-equation-converted-to-the-other-form) could be repeated also here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can "flatten" the equation:

$$R_{TH}=\frac{R_1R_2}{R_1+R_2}\leftrightarrow R_{TH}R_1+R_{TH}R_2=R_1R_2$$

Then move the terms and "unflatten",

$$R_1R_2-R_{TH}R_1=R_{TH}R_2\leftrightarrow R_1=\frac{R_{TH}R_2}{R_2-R_{TH}}.$$

Answer (score 1):

You simply multiply, factor out and divide:

$$R_{TH} = \frac{R_1 R_2}{R_1+R_2}$$

$$(R_1+R_2)R_{TH} = R_1 R_2$$

$$R_{1}(R_{TH}-R_2) = -R_2 R_{TH}$$

$$R_1 = \frac{R_2 R_{TH}}{R_2 - R_{TH}}$$